# How to extract only number from string which start with number using MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

How to extract the only number from string which starts with number in MongoDB

I want to extract the number from a string which starts with the number.

I have a collection which contains document like

```
  {
    "address" :"1103 wood crest"
  },
  {
    "address": "223 NW 28TH ST"
  },
  {
    "address": "NW 28TH ST"
  },
  {
    "address": "28TH ST ava"
   }
```

I want to write aggregation query, which gives result in below format: below:

```
{
  "number": "1103",
  "address" :"wood crest"
},
{
  "number": "223",
  "address": "223 NW 28TH ST"
},
{
  "number": "",
  "address": "NW 28TH ST"
},
{
   "number": "",
   "address": "28TH ST ava"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't do this with the aggregation framework. Your best bet here is [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)

```
db.coll.mapReduce(
    function() { 
        var fields = {}; 
        fields["number"] = parseInt(this.address.match(/^\d+?\s+/)) || "";
        fields["address"] =  this.address; 
        emit(this._id, fields); 
    }, 
    function(key, value) {}, 
    { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

which returns something like this:

```
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("57691c0206c5c92152979d3e"),
                        "value" : {
                                "number" : 1103,
                                "address" : "1103 wood crest"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("57691c0206c5c92152979d3f"),
                        "value" : {
                                "number" : 223,
                                "address" : "223 NW 28TH ST"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("57691c0206c5c92152979d40"),
                        "value" : {
                                "number" : "",
                                "address" : "NW 28TH ST"
                        }
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("57691c0206c5c92152979d41"),
                        "value" : {
                                "number" : "",
                                "address" : "28TH ST ava"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 25,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 4,
                "emit" : 4,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 4
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```